# Getting index position of a div generated dinamically and stored in an array with a onclick function inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays, one contains all the divs generated and another one contains empty positions (later I fill them with a json). I need to find the exact position of the box I clicked so I can load also the exact position of the json array and edit it.

```
var counter = '';
    var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'new-box';       
        div.onclick = modifyBox;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
        boxStorage.push(div);
        console.log(boxStorage)
        boxContentStorage.push(counter);
        console.log(boxContentStorage)
```

With var counter I add "" to each position so I always have the same size in the array of boxes and array of json. How can I return the index of each div I click so I can have control of the position in both arrays?

My code:

http://codepen.io/pablocgdev/pen/AXYkPG

Currently the button for modify isn't working as intended, when clicking a box and filling the fields you should edit that position of the json array, so box 1 is attached to json 1, box 2 to json 2...

Comment: better use angular, code later in answer,refer https://angularjs.org/

Comment: sadly this is not an option, my app is 90% developed and I have no time for migrating to angular.

Comment: ok, so assign your counter to items in both arrays, and use more code to fix two way data binding

Comment: So per my understanding, you have a list of divs out of which, some can be empty. Now you need position of this div so you can populate from JSON. Am I right?

Comment: I'll upload my code for better understanding.

Comment: 1 small hack. You are creating divs dynamically. So you can add a data-attribute say `data-position=index` and then use in in your function

Comment: I also can control them with json, I don't care, just need to have control of both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, this will cast the DOM elements into an array and then will return the index of the clicked element

```js
function getIndexOfDiv() {
   var divList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('new-box'));

   // pass the currently clicked div
   return divList.indexOf(this);
}
```

Comment: Little fix, you mispelled getElementsByClassName. I've tried this before and always outputs the same: Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.slice called on null or undefined

Comment: Yeah, now it will work fine. I some how referred that u have used another div as parent of divlist.